# How to retrieve observable set in rx (reactive) pipe in Python?

Tags: python, system.reactive

I'm using rx for creating simulatneous loading from few sources.

```
rx.from_list(files).pipe(
        ops.map(lambda file: self._dataflow()),
        ops.subscribe_on(pool_scheduler)
    ).subscribe(on_next=lambda file: print(file),
                on_error=print,
                on_completed=lambda: print("PROCESS done!"))
```

I want my `map` function to return observable object that is being return type for `_dataflow()`  function. If I use just `_dataflow()` instead `ops.map(lambda file: self._dataflow())` it work finely, however, I want to use some condition that for any `file` in `files` I would choose different functions like `_dataflow()`. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, your closest choice in [merge](https://ninmesara.github.io/RxPY/api/operators/merge.html#operator-merge) operator:

```
list=rx.from_list(["set1_file1","set1_file2","set2_file1","set2_file2"])

rx.merge(list.pipe(ops.filter(lambda x:"set1" in x),ops.map(lambda x:x+" from list1 printed")),list.pipe(ops.filter(lambda x:"set2" in x),ops.map(lambda x:x+" from list2 printed"))).subscribe(lambda x:print(x))
```

Replace the lambdas with your desired Mapping functions.

Comment: That is the thing I've been looking for. Thank you!